# how to customized a ubuntu server 22.04 image and set up as a auto answer installtion image

Tags: server, 22.04, preseed, cd-image, autoinstall

i am trying to make an image for my machines. There are too many machines that i have to install windows server and ubuntu server on them. So i need to customized a image(install some software and write some configuration) and using it to create new ISO image. For windows server, i can just use sysprep and write a unattend.xml file to achieve the auto installtion. But now the question is, how to do the same things for the ubuntu server 22.04

Comment: have you already checked this: https://www.ventoy.net/

Comment: See the Ubuntu Server documentation, which includes a section on this topic: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart